# Facebook: PHP SDK issues

Tags: php, sdk, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I have some facebook php code that worked flawlessly before the `4/30/15` upgrade. I upgraded my code, it seems to work on certain computers but not on others.  On computers that it doesn't work on I've tried multiple browsers with the same result.  I am able to log into Facebook using the SDK, but it won't post anything to my page's wall.  Same code, different computer, and everything works fine.  Here's the code:

```
    <?php
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => '##########',
    'secret' => '##########',
    'fileUpload' => true
));
$user     = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
    try {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    }
    catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }
}
if ($user) {
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array(
        'next' => ($user['baseurl'] . 'logout.php')
    ));
} else {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'scope' => 'publish_pages , manage_pages'
    ));
}
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$params       = array(
    'access_token' => $access_token
);
#The id of the fanpage
$fanpage      = '############';
#The id of the album
$album_id     = '############';
if ($user) {
    $accounts = $facebook->api('/me/accounts', 'GET', $params);
    foreach ($accounts['data'] as $account) {
        if ($account['id'] == $fanpage || $account['name'] == $fanpage) {
            $fanpage_token = $account['access_token'];
        }
    }
    $message = 'Post this to the wall.';
    $img     = 'path to image.jpg';
    $args    = array(
        'message' => $message,
        'image' => '@' . $img,
        'aid' => $album_id,
        'no_story' => 0,
        'access_token' => $fanpage_token
    );
    $photo   = $facebook->api($album_id . '/photos', 'post', $args);
}
?>
```

Comment: are publish_pages and manage_pages approved? well, most likely they are not, see my answer.

Comment: All users of the app have either admin or editor roles.

Comment: So my error log is showing this: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions.  It seems like facebook is attempting to post as the user to my page wall rather than as the page to the page wall? Despite the fact that the code grabs the fanpage token via $account['access_token']?

Answer (score 0):

Most permissions need to get approved by Facebook before they can be used for any user, else they only work for users with a role in the App. Check out the docs about [Login Review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/what-is-login-review).

You can only use `publish_pages` and `manage_pages` as App Admin/Developer/Tester without review.

If you only test with those users and it still does not work, debug the Access Token in the Debugger and see if those permissions are really authorized: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Edit: After reading your comment, i believe you are trying to use a User Token. Use /me/accounts to get a Page Token and try again with that one. If you debug the Token, make sure the Page shows up too.

Comment: All users of the app have either admin or editor roles.

Comment: i´ve added some more information, you may need to check the token in the debugger

Comment: Not seeing anything under the debugger... under scopes both manage_pages and publish_pages are there.  I can't get my head around why this code works on one computer and not on another when the code is hosted on a server.

Comment: well, you can try to catch exceptions. should be done anyway.

Comment: pro tip: use the javascript sdk for login. it´s much easier and much better.

Comment: So my error log is showing this: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions

Comment: It seems like facebook is attempting to post as the user to my page wall rather than as the page to the page wall?  Despite the fact that the code grabs the fanpage token via $account['access_token']?

Comment: looks like you are using a user token, not a page token